# String with 2 number parameters

Tags: vue-i18n

In my laravel 5.6 / vue.js 2.5.7/ @kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0" application I 
set a label as

'selected_active_users'     => 'Selected {selected_active_users_count} user(s) from {active_users_selection_length} active user(s)',

and in vue I tried to write

```
{{ $tc('event.selected_active_users', selected_active_users_count, { selected_active_users_count: selected_active_users_count, active_users_selection_length :
    activeUsersSelectionArray.length }) }}
```

and I have resulting string  as

```
Selected 3 user(s) from 5 active user(s)
```

That is good, but I want to active user/active user(s) depending on active_users_selection_length in a condition.
That is clear how to use it in 1 condition/string but I failed   to use it in a combined string.
Is it possible and if yes which is syntax?

Thanks!